# Ubuntu can't connect wifi after installing second hard drive

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hard-drive, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

My laptop originally came with windows installed, which I removed, and instead installed Ubuntu. (This has been working until now) I bought a new hard drive and installed it in the open slot, and installed windows on it.

Now, the windows hard drive is working and can connect use wifi and everything etc, but the Ubuntu side can't connect to wifi.

Upon booting, the wifi icon looks something like this: <--> . Clicking on it says "Ethernet Network disconnected". I have never had an Ethernet connection, and in the network manager, I only have wifi connections to edit.

Switching "enable networking" off and then on again changes the icon to the Up-Down-Arrows icon, but the drop-down menu doesn't change.

Previously, I had the issue that "device was not managed" and edited the network manager conf files to set managed to true and unmanaged to none, which solved that issue, but now is stuck here.

Comment: As always, when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must.

Comment: Thank you! That really solved the problem, though I don't follow how it was related?

Comment: Fast Startup is Windows trickery to make  it look like Windows boots faster than it actually does by keeping it semi-hibernated instead of fully shutting down. One of the collateral effects is hijacking some devices and preventing the correct hardware initialization when you reboot into the other OS (Ubuntu).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for explaining!